# Java interacting directly with a DB file

Tags: java, database

Before I started learning and using Java I used VB. In VB, a program can open a Microsoft Access database file and view/edit the records. VB has a component that handles the file and parsing. What I am looking for is a Java program that can open a database file directly. What I am not looking for is Java communicating with a SQL server a database server or any other kind of server. I have tried to search the net for Java and databases but all I am able to find is Java protocols that communicate with a server or a Java server service. Those items fill the search records on all of the search engines I have tried. I have found that DB's can be XML, and that Java can open them but, it seems that it no longer preserves the relational aspects. I may be wrong on that fact, I am uncertain.

A. Can Java open a local DB file?
B. Can that preserve the relational aspects?
C. Can multiple Java programs open the same DB file?
D. If a Java program on computer A modifies the DB file will the Java program on computer B know about that change and update itself?

Assuming they are not modifying the same record. The type of DB file is not that important to but it would be nice if it could be opened by MS Access. It would also be nice if it could be open by JAVADB. Neither of those two are required.

E. what kind of components or projects could meet this need?

Comment: It's possible to read and write Access databases from Java - see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21955257/185034).

Comment: A: Yes, B: Yes, C: Yes, D: Depends on how you program it

Answer (score 0):

Pure Java hasn't graphic design. Some degree of design of databases have IDE, for example Eclipse in perspectives: Database Debug, Database development. Can view tables, design columns etc.
It isn't full desktop tool for (semi) amateur computer worker.
In Java can write full comfortable user database program (in example Open Office "Base" has some dependencies to Java), with filling similar to entry level access.

Answer (score 0):

For simpler database like [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) there are several java projects that you can use, for example [sqlite 4 java](https://bitbucket.org/almworks/sqlite4java).

Sqlite is pretty good these days and for small databases a good choice.